# Format decimal value in JQuery: From 2 to 4 decimals only showing significant values (not 0)

Tags: jquery, number-formatting

I'm trying to format any number like `123.40` in jQuery using

```
`decimals.toFixed(4);` // round
```

That is giving to me a result like `123.4000`, but I want only `123.40` and if the value is `123.4786` then it should show `123.4786`.

I want to use min value `2` and max value `4` for decimal formatting like we are doing in `JSP fmt.tld` tag file can any one suggest how I can achieve this.

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: Did you tried `decimals.toFixed(2);`

Comment: and what about `123.4088`

Comment: if number is 123.407 then it remain as 123.407 and if value is 123.44 then it remain 123.44 not 123.4400 i tried to use decimals.toFixed(4); max value will be 4